# GUI sounds creation / game audio

Tags: sfx, gameaudio

please advise.

There are three examples of games sounds I'm trying to produce (casual/HO game, so maximum sound realism is a must).

https://audioboo.fm/ableton_in_ua

First two are relatively simple - arped/sequenced sound with delay as I get it.

But the third one "Clue Found" sounds like combination of a sample + short synth sound.
Am I right here? Is it right way to go? Any info will be appreciated.

Andrey

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful information about designing interface sounds for a casual game.
https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/11608/1225

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a synth sound mixed with a bell tree sample. Hear it on its own [here](http://www.compositiontoday.com/sound_bank/percussion/bell_tree.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response, Mark! I've checked this resource in and out, looked through all major books in the field - but not too much info there. Do you know a good info source with systematic approach on that?

Comment: Well, not really sure what you mean. It's just a recording of a bell tree, possibly with some basic effects like eq or reverb mixed with a synth sound. Are you after how to make the synth sound also? Just listening again, there's also a click type sound mixed in as a third layer.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. What I mean is something like a Guide or Book or Video where major production tips for these kind of sounds are mentioned, if you know any.

Comment: Ok sure, I've never found a guide that specific for individual effects. It's really just listening, trial and error. Having said that I think a similar sound has come before here, so trawling the archives is often time well spent.